# Javascript. How to check if a false boolean parameter is passed in a function?

Tags: javascript

I have a function which has a parameter:

```
function checkThis(isAlive) {
    // Blah blah
}
```

How do I check if the parameter `isAlive` was passed, even if it was passed as false?

`isAlive` must be a boolean.

Comment: you can use `typeof isAlive === 'boolean' or `=== false`

Comment: Do you mean making sure some value was actually passed as opposed to not like `checkThis(false)` vs `checkThis()`

Comment: Thanks @RichChurcher, similar but that question doesn't specifically deal with boolean parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do I check if the parameter `isAlive` was passed, even if it was passed as false?

This is how I did it:

```
function checkThis(isAlive) {
   if (isAlive !== undefined && !isAlive) {
      console.log("isAlive is defined AND it is false");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna check if the parameter was passed you should check if its value is `undefined`, otherwise it was set:

```js
function checkThis(isAlive) {
    if (isAlive === undefined) {
      console.log("isAlive was not set")
    } else {
      console.log(`isAlive was set and its value is ${isAlive}`)
    }
}

checkThis()
checkThis("I am")
checkThis(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check [`arguments.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

```js
function checkThis(isAlive) {
    return arguments.length && isAlive === false ? 'Passed false arguments' : isAlive
}

console.log(checkThis())
console.log(checkThis(undefined))
console.log(checkThis("I am"))
console.log(checkThis(false))
```